# WSO2 Identity Server as an IDP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

My Use case is a very simple one . I want to use WSO2 Identity Server to implement SAML2.0 SSO in our app deployment .

- We **don't** have an external identity provider like facebook or
  google , so we want the identity server itself to act like an
  identity provider , [Local Authentication ]
- We want the authentication for the SP to be done against a local user
  store [AD]
- The SSO login is going to be IDP initiated.
- The login page has to be customized.

I went through the documentation tutorials and while the architecture page does mention that all this is possible ,  but I could not find any actual tutorial which explains how to do this .

Can someone link me to the tutorial pages which describe how to do this or , provide a rundown of the steps required ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes all of these are possible with WSO2 Identity Server. Unfortunately there isn't any single tutorial/documentation to cover this in single but I can provide you each for every step.

1. [Configuring active directory.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-Write+Active+Directory+User+Store)
2. [SSO with SAML.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Single+Sign-On)
3. [IDP Initiated SSO.](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/12/08/idp-initiated-saml2-sso-with-identity-server/)
4. [Customizing login page.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Customizing+Login+Pages)

And if you need to know about more advance scenarios, please read this [article](https://medium.facilelogin.com/thirty-solution-patterns-with-the-wso2-identity-server-16f9fd0c0389).